# How to have a method return a started Task without blocking?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

In my C# app, I've been able to start concurrent tasks that make http calls and then wait for all of them to complete.

```
var responseTasks = new List<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>();

// PostChanges makes an async http call and returns the task
responseTasks.Add(myServiceClient.PostChanges(json));
responseTasks.Add(myServiceClient.PostChanges(json));
responseTasks.Add(myServiceClient.PostChanges(json));

Task.WaitAll(responseTasks.ToArray());
```

But what if each of the calls to PostChanges relies on a call that gets data from an http request?  What is the simplest way to create a method that encapsulates the two calls and returns a started task?  The method would have to make both requests something like this:

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetDataAndPostChanges(MyInput input)
{
    var json = myServiceClient.GetData(input); // this call must complete first
    var response = myServiceClient.PostChanges(json);
    return response; // how to actually return a task immediately that does both calls?
}
```

I would then want to make concurrent calls to that method and wait for all of them to complete.

```
var responseTasks = new List<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>();

// PostChanges makes an async http call and returns the task
responseTasks.Add(myServiceClient.GetDataAndPostChanges(input1));
responseTasks.Add(myServiceClient.GetDataAndPostChanges(input2));
responseTasks.Add(myServiceClient.GetDataAndPostChanges(input3));

Task.WaitAll(responseTasks.ToArray());
```

Comment: await the `PostChanges` within the function. Is `GetData` sync or async?

Comment: Right now GetData is not async, but it just calls GetAsync on an HttpClient and returns the response content as a list of objects, so it can be turned into an async method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the function async and await the necessary calls

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetDataAndPostChanges(MyInput input) {
    var json = await myServiceClient.GetData(input); // this call must complete first
    var response = await myServiceClient.PostChanges(json);
    return response;
}
```

The assumption above is that `GetData` is an asynchronous function.

Comment: I assume that with this implementation, PostChanges won't be called until GetData completes?

Comment: @JimSweeney that is correct. code will await GetData then call PostChanges